# Prove that a subset of R is an interval, if it contains a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis

Have a nice day, everyone! I'm kind of stuck on the following task and I don't really know how to prove that part with "if and only if". I'd appreciate any help.
The task itself is: 
"Prove that a set $X \subset \Bbb R$ is an interval (any: open, half, or closed) if and only if for any $a,b \in X$, closed interval $[a,b]$ is contained in $X$."
The task is right after the paragraph "Properties of functions, which are continuous on a closed interval",  and in the beginning of paragraph "Continuousness and points of discontinuity of a monotonic function".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Formatting hint: You get nice typesetting if you enclose your formulas in dollar signs (but `\R` needs to be replaced with `\mathbb R`)

Comment: On the mathematics: Which part do you have problems with, the "if" or the "only if"?

Comment: Look at the interval $\{\inf X, \sup X\}$, where the braces are either brackets of parentheses depending on the bound being an element of $X$ or not. By definition of $\inf$, if $\inf X< c$, then there is $a\in X$ with $a<c$. Likewise, if $c<\sup X$ there is $b\in X$ with $c<b$. Therefore, $[a,b]\subset X$. It follows that $c\in X$. Hence, $\{\inf X, \sup X\}\subset X$. Since $\inf X$ and $\sup X$ are bounds of $X$ you also have $\{\inf X, \sup X\}\supset X$. Therefore, $\{\inf X, \sup X\}= X$.

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading, there's an interval that does not contain a closed interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x \in X$. Let $c=\inf X$. 
Case 1): $c=-\infty$. For any positive integer $N$ there exist $y \in X$ such that $y <-N$. By hypothesis $[y,x] \subset X$. This implies $[-N,x] \subset X$. Since $N$ is arbitrary we get $(\infty, x] \subset $X$.

Case 2): $c >-\infty$. For any $N$ there exist $y \in X$ such that $y <c+\frac  1 N$. By hypothesis $[c+\frac  1 N, x] \subset X$. Since $N$ is arbitrary we get $(c, x] \subset X$.

Now a similar argument shows that if $d=\sup X$ then $[x,d) \subset X$. Putting these together we conclude that $(c,d) \subset X$. From the definition of $c$ and $d$ it follows that $X \subset [c,d]$ (in case $c$ and $d$ are finite). It is now clear that $X$ must be on of the intervals $(c,d), [c,d),(c,d], [c,d]$.

Comment: You have not dealt with the case where $\inf X$ does  not exist. (In this case $X=\emptyset$ and we are done.)

Comment: For the 2nd case N is still an integer? And N of any sign?

Comment: @GuyFawkes $N$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Thank you. That works :)